# ¿Como usar un iterador de un vector de vector de pares en C++?

Tags: c++, vectores, iteradores, contenedores

```
class enrutador{

public:
    void mejorRuta(int V,int E, int nodo_inicio);
    void visualizar_router();
private:
    map<char,int> router;
    map<char,int> ::iterator I1;

    typedef pair<int, int> ii;//<vecino, costo>
    typedef vector<ii> vii;//todos los vecinos asociados--vector de pares
    vector<vii> adjLis;//vector de vector de pares
    vector<vii> ::iterator I3;
};
```

> Donde uso el iterador pero no se como usarlo

```
for (I3=adjLis.begin();I3!=adjLis.end();I3++){
    cout<<*I3 <<endl;
}
```

> Me sale error en la linea del cout. No sé como usar un iterador para ese contenedor. Agradezco su ayuda.[image: Me sale este error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que el vector de vector de pares es una estructura de datos de tres dimensiones: La primera dimensión es un vector, la segunda es otro vector y la tercera es un par; así que como mínimo necesitarás dos bucles, uno para el vector de vectores y otro para cada vector del vector de vectores:

```
for (const auto &vector_interno : adjLis)
{
    for (const auto &par : vector_interno)
    {
        std::cout << par.first << ' ' << par.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue muy útil